# Disabling Extent Based Rendering using ESRI Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, scale, feature-layer

I am using ESRI's javascript API to generate a heatmap renderer for my feature layer. I am noticing that the heatmap calculation/visualization is dependent upon what is in the current zoom extent. For instance, when I observe the map at the World zoom extent, the map indicates there are clusters (see first attached image). However, when zooming into one of said clusters, the cluster disappears and is instead replaced with very faint highlighting (see second attached image).

I believe this is due to the fact that the renderer calculates the visualization of the heatmap based on which datapoints are contained within the current zoom extent. I am looking for a way to disable this functionality such that the visualization remains consistent regardless of what zoom level the user is on.

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]